# Multithreading requests without a URL list

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

I'm currently trying to make my requests faster by multithreading them but I'm not sure how to do it the way I want. I know about grequests but they seem to require a URL list. I have code with a starting number contained in URL and would like all threads to stop after getting a status_code of 200

I have tried to accomplish this by grequests but couldn't make it work. Also tried threading but don't know how to stop all threads after working URL was found

```py
import requests
import webbrowser

def url_request(number):
    url = "http://website.com/download/" + str(number) + ".zip"
    r = requests.head(url)
    if r.status_code == 404:
        print(url + " - 404 Not Found!")
        number += 1
        url_request(number)
    elif r.status_code == 200:
        webbrowser.open(url)
        print(url + " - 200 Found!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url_request(int(input("Starting number: ")))
```

What I want the code to do is execute multiple `request.head` at once with a number after "Starting number" and will stop after one of the threads finds url with status_code 200.

Comment: Why don't you pre-build the list of urls and then send all the requests in parallel?

Comment: @DroidX86 Well, I could try that, of course. But I wanted to be able to set the starting point and not have any preexisting lists.

Comment: If you don't want a pre-existing lists, try writing a generator that will generate the URLs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Thanks for your advice.

Here's the code:

```py
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import grequests
import webbrowser


def url_request_threaded(startnumber, stopnumber):
    urls = []
    for i in range(startnumber, stopnumber):
        urls.append("http://website.com/download/" + str(i) + ".zip")
    gr = (grequests.head(url, stream=False) for url in urls)
    gresponses = grequests.imap(gr, size=10)
    try:
        for response in gresponses:
            if response.status_code == 404:
                print(response.url + " - 404 Not Found!")
            elif response.status_code == 200:
                webbrowser.open(response.url)
                print(response.url + " - 200 Found!")
                raise SystemExit
    except SystemExit:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            startn = input("Starting number: ")
            startn = int(startn)
            stopn = input("End number: ")
            stopn = int(stopn)
            url_request_threaded(b, v, startn, stopn)
        except ValueError:
            print("Must be a number!")
            continue
        break
```